# Handling % sign in the string attribute in weka

Tags: weka, arff

I have a arrf file which is like this

```
@relation training_set
@attribute URL string
@attribute DOI numeric
@attribute ISBN numeric
@attribute Conclusions numeric

@attribute Source_Type {Scientific, Non_Scientific}
@data
http://www.nejm.org/doi/full/10.1056/nejmra1002842 , 0 , 0 , 1 , 0 , Scientific 
http://www.plosone.org/article/info%3adoi%2f10.1371%2fjournal.pone.0014270#pone-0014270-t003 , 1 , 0 , 1 , 0 , Scientific
```

I have a problem in loading this file to weka because I have a "%" sign in the url data. I know that % are treated as comments in weka but is there a way to fetch this kind of string ? I am not making URL as a nominal data because it is an identifier in the training set ?

Answer (score 0):

By wrapping the string in single-quotes, I was able to load your file successfully into Weka (I also added another attribute to match the structure of your data):

```
@relation training_set
@attribute URL string
@attribute DOI numeric
@attribute ISBN numeric
@attribute Conclusions numeric
@attribute Binary numeric
@attribute Source_Type {Scientific, Non_Scientific}
@data
'http://www.nejm.org/doi/full/10.1056/nejmra1002842' , 0 , 0 , 1 , 0 , Scientific 
'http://www.plosone.org/article/info%3adoi%2f10.1371%2fjournal.pone.0014270#pone-0014270-t003' , 1 , 0 , 1 , 0 , Scientific
```

Hope this Helps!